# Uploading remote image via Foursquare API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foursquare, image-uploading

I'm trying to post a photo using the foursquare API (via the foursquare2 gem).

Per their docs, I must pass the :photo parameter as an UploadIO(Object).

http://rubydoc.info/gems/foursquare2/Foursquare2/Photos

When I attempt to make the call I get a "No such file or directory error"

```
foursquare.add_photo(:checkinId => XXX, :photo => Faraday::UploadIO.new('http://dagh1lffffqbm.cloudfront.net/1372702207.733335_13939.jpg', 'image/jpeg'))
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - http://dagh1lffffqbm.cloudfront.net/1372702207.733335_13939.jpg
```

Note that the file I'm trying upload is remote (on S3) and not on my server. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by adding an `open` call around the image path:

```
foursquare.add_photo(:checkinId => XXX, :photo => Faraday::UploadIO.new(open("http://dagh1lffffqbm.cloudfront.net/1372702207.733335_13939.jpg"), 'image/jpeg'))
```

Now whether this is the most efficient way of doing this, that I'm not sure. I have a sneaking suspicion that this is actually downloading the S3 file onto my server before sending over to foursquare. Perhaps thats the only way?